# Bundles depending on the year

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the folowing bundless

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/2013").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/2013/app.js",
                        "~/Scripts/2013/controllers/*.js",
                        "~/Scripts/2013/directives.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/2014").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/2014/app.js",
                        "~/Scripts/2014/controllers/*.js",
                        "~/Scripts/2014/directives.js"));
```

how to set the year into a variable to obtain such that it

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/{year}").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/{year}/app.js",
                        "~/Scripts/{year}/controllers/*.js",
                        "~/Scripts/{year}/directives.js"));
```

and in front-end

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/@currentyear")
```

Answer (score 1):

is not more simple create do something like this :

```
var string year=now.Year;

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/"+ year).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/"+year+"/app.js",
                    "~/Scripts/"+year+"/controllers/*.js",
                    "~/Scripts/"+year+"/directives.js"));

Session.Add("bundleyear",year);
```

then in page

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/" +<%=Session("bundleyear").tostring())
```